# Android Studio 4.2.1 (6) Problems

Tags: android-studio

OS Windows 10 64-bit.
Freshly installed Android Studio 4.2.1 has 6 next to the Problems tab but no problems to show.
Anyone has the same and, if yes, why? What does it mean?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try gradle Refresh?

App and Project grandle refresh

Comment: Thanks for your answer but...what do you mean Gradle refersh? Resync you mean? done it 20 times...still the 6 next to Problems. You saying that you have Android Studio 4.2.1 on Windows 10 and don't get the 6?